# Formatação de Datas em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, data

poderiam me ajudar por gentileza?

Gostaria de utilizar a função abaixo em uma lógica que estou criando, porém eu precisaria que a função abaixo retornasse para mim apenas a ultima semana do mês, não estou conseguindo entender como realizar as devidas alterações nela para que funcione da forma que eu quero, se puderem me ajudar eu agradeço.

```js
function formataData(data) {
 var diaS = data.getDay();
 var diaM = data.getDate();
 var mes = data.getMonth();
 var ano = data.getFullYear();
 
 switch (diaS) { //converte o numero em nome do dia
  case 0:
   diaS = "Domingo";
   break;
  case 1: 
   diaS = "Segunda-feira";
   break;
  case 2:
   diaS = "Terça-feira";
   break;
  case 3:
   diaS = "Quarta-feira";
   break;
  case 4:
   diaS = "Quinta-feira";
   break;
  case 5:
   diaS = "Sexta-feira";
   break;
  case 6:
   diaS = "Sabado";
   break;
  }

 switch (mes) { //converte o numero em nome do mês
  case 0:
   mes = "Janeiro";
   break;
  case 1:
   mes = "Fevereiro";
   break;
  case 2:
   mes = "Março";
   break;
  case 3:
   mes = "Abril";
   break;
  case 4:
   mes = "Maio";
   break;
  case 5:
   mes = "Junho";
   break;
  case 6:
   mes = "Julho";
   break;
  case 7:
   mes = "Agosto";
   break;
  case 8:
   mes = "Setembro";
   break;
  case 9:
   mes = "Outubro";
   break;
  case 10:
   mes = "Novembro";
   break;
  case 11:
   mes = "Dezembro";
   break;
  }
 
  if (diaM.toString().length == 1)
      diaM = "0"+diaM;
  if (mes.toString().length == 1)
      mes = "0"+mes;
 
 return diaS + ", " + diaM + "/" + mes + "/" + ano;
}

var d = new Date();
var anoC = d.getFullYear();
var mesC = d.getMonth();

var d1 = new Date (anoC, mesC, 1);
var d2 = new Date (anoC, mesC+1, 0);

console.log(formataData(d1));
console.log(formataData(d2));
```

Comment: O que você quer? fazer? Listar as datas da última semana do mês de segunda a sexta?

Comment: Isso mesmo @Marcondes, quero listar somente a ultima semana do mês.

Comment: Pega o último dia do mês e verifica se é uma sexta-feira, se não for decrementa um e testa novamente. Até encontrar a data daquele mês que é. Depois disso tu sabe que daquela ponto -4 será as datas da última semana do mês, serve?

Comment: Diga qual seria a ultima semana de julho esperada por você.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja isso se ajuda.

```
var datateste = new Date(218,06,27,0,0,0,0); //data, aqui tem que pegar a última data de uma semana cheia do mês atual.
var primeiro = datateste.getDate() - datateste.getDay(); // Primeiro dia é o dia do mês - o dia da semana, contando o Domingo 
var ultimo = primeiro + 6; // primeiro dia + 6, para pegar o sábado
var dataInicial = new Date(datateste.setDate(primeiro));//aqui você pode fazer primeiro + 1 se quer iniciar somente pela segunda-feira
dataInicial = "" + (dataInicial.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dataInicial.getDate() + "/" + dataInicial.getFullYear();
var dataFInal = new Date(datateste.setDate(ultimo));
dataFInal = "" + (dataFInal.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dataFInal.getDate() + "/" + dataFInal.getFullYear();
```

Comment: De domingo até sábado. Você pode mudar isso para var ultimo = primeiro + 5; ou 4 se iniciar na segunda feira.

Comment: Cara, é isso mesmo que eu estava precisando, obrigado pela força, estarei implementando no meu desenvolvimento.

Comment: Quem é `last` ?

Comment: ajustado @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: @GabrielPaixãoJustino então se deu boa da um votinho na resposta.